# Spark & Scala: can't get MappedRDD to perferm groupByKey from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am facing a disappointing issue while trying to use `groupByKey` or any function of a PairRDD or MappedRDD. What I get is that I have always just a `RDD` and I don't know how to convert it (really I am quite sure that the conversion should be automatically detected by Scala). My code is the following:

```
val broadcastedDistanceMeasure = sc.broadcast(dbScanSettings.distanceMeasure)
val distances = input.cartesian(input)
  .filter(t => t._1!=t._2)
  .map( { 
    case(p1, p2) => (p1) -> broadcastedDistanceMeasure.value.distance(p1,p2)
  })
```

where `input` is a `RDD`. And the resulting type according to Eclise and `sbt run` is actually a `RDD`. So I cannot perform a `groupByKey` operation. If I try almost the same code on the spark shell, instead, I get a `MappedRDD`.

This is my `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0"
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Greetings.

Marco

Comment: Perhaps you don't see the `groupByKey` operation just because you are NOT importing `org.apache.spark.SparkContext._`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that inside the IDE, you will never see the MappedRDD type for any RDD, since this is provided as an implicit conversion in the Spark Scala API. If you look for example at the [source of `SparkContext`](https://github.com/amplab/graphx/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala) you will see the implicit conversions from the common RDD to the specialized RDDs richer interfaces as `PairRDDFunctions`, and from inside this specialized interfaces then you can use functions as `groupByKey` which are made available thanks to the implicit conversions. So, in short, I think you only need to import `org.apache.spark.SparkContext._` in order to achieve what you want.

In this particular case, I think the specific conversion is

```
implicit def rddToPairRDDFunctions[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, V)]) =
    new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
```

which wraps the RDD into a [PairRDDFunctions](https://github.com/amplab/graphx/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala), which in turns contains the `groupByKey` operation.

Hope it helped.